# tableview to tableview protocol delegates

Tags: swift, delegates, tableview, segue, protocols

I am trying to finish this app that is a form. once filled out a button later will be pushed for print. The first controller has a tableview that has page 1 page 2 page 3. page 1 opens and you fill in all info. when hit save it should take you back to first controller. then when you push print opens the tableview and loads all info.
I am struggling to use structs correctly. also struggling on the save button to the delegate to the print controller page.

[image]

my page controller code

```
class PagesController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    var pages = ["Page 1","Page 2","Page 3"]

    @IBOutlet weak var pagesTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pagesTableView.delegate = self
        pagesTableView.dataSource = self

    }

    @IBAction func printBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    } }

extension PagesController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pages.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PagesCell")

        cell?.textLabel?.text = pages[indexPath.row]

        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ChildInfoSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 90.0
    }
     }
```

Heres my form controller

```
protocol ChildDelegate {
    func saveInfoBlock(form: ChildInfo)
}

class ChildInfoTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var formDelegate: ChildDelegate!

    var firstNameText: UITextField = UITextField()
    var lastNameText: UITextField = UITextField()
    var middleNameText: UITextField = UITextField()

    //MARK: From ChildInfo.swift STRUCT
    var childInfo = [ChildInfo]()

    var basicChildInfo = ["Child's First Name","Child's Middle Name","Child's Last Name"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return basicChildInfo.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChildInfoCell") as! ChildInfoTableViewCell

        cell.formLabel.text = basicChildInfo[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    //MARK: Segue to printController
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let path = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

        let destViewController = segue.destination as! PrintPageTableViewController

    }

    //MARK: Cancel Button Pressed
    @IBAction func cancelBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let firstname = firstNameText.text ?? ""
        let middlename = middleNameText.text ?? ""
        let lastname = lastNameText.text ?? ""

        let formData = ChildInfo(cFirstName: firstname, cMiddleName: middlename, cLastName: lastname)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

         formDelegate.saveInfoBlock(form: formData)

        saveInfoBLock()
    }

    func saveInfoBLock() {
        print("Saving Info")

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Heres my struct that I don't properly use

```
struct ChildInfo {

    var childFirstName: String?
    var childMiddleName: String?
    var childLastName: String?


    var childsMadeUpName: String = ""

    init(cFirstName: String, cMiddleName: String, cLastName: String) {
        self.childFirstName = cFirstName
        self.childMiddleName = cMiddleName
        self.childLastName = cLastName
    }

}
```

and lastly my tableviewcell

```
class ChildInfoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var formText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var formLabel: UILabel!



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Once the delegate protocol gets passed. What would a put in the printtableviewcontroller to make the data show? I had someone help me on here, but It was all programmatically and I'm no that advanced yet.

Comment: Hey, so let me see if I understand your question.. You have a tableView, when you click on a cell ( Page 1 ) it takes you to another view to fill out some information, then you hit save to go back to the first view with the view controller. Then you want to hit print and this action should take you to a new view which displays the information ? 

Is this what you are asking ?

Comment: yes this is correct. I can get to page 1 it has the list of items in an array. but I was told it will be easier with a struct. still trying to figure out how to implement that

Comment: The struct is fine, a struct is just an object, same as a class or an enum. What you want to do is be able to transfer this object around with segues.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can do:

1. Use delegation. I am assuming this is what you want to achieve here.
2. Pass your data through Segues. ( Recommended )

To use delegation, you have to have a clear concept of how delegation works.

Here is a link to an explanation I gave someone on another site. It breaks it down, I think this may help you a bit.

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/totally-confused-with-the-example-used

For now, I think the solution to your problem is to use Segues.

When you tap on the button to take you to the ChildInfoTableViewController where you fill the information is where you want to create your "ChildInfo" object. Then when you press save, you trigger the segue and pass the "ChildInfo" object to the "PagesController".

Then from there, that same object should be pass through the segue into the print view.

Comment: and I am okay with this option. I didn't know it could hold info from more than one controller. after they hit save. they then need to go back and fill out page 2. save. page 3. save. then hit the print button to relay ALL the info. I know how to do standard easy segues. I guess this one is one I have never tried

Comment: @BlueMoose, this may not be part of your question, but I strongly suggest you look at user functionality. Instead of having them go back and fill out information then hit save, and then go back 2 more times to fill out more information, you should have one page where they fill out all the required information at once. Then hit save to be transfer back into the original view controller.

Comment: @j Arango I know how to make the label and textfield in a custom cell to make an array for the labels as questions and the textfields as text. how do I make that info pull into another tableview in order. do I use .append? or something similar to that?